# C++ thread loop and system_error

Tags: c++, multithreading, destructor

I used `std::thread` in my code and there's a part of creating threads, `join`, and repeat it until the process is done. However, memory usage increased over time and crashed. At first I thought it's because of pointer so I changed all of `thread*` to `thread`, but it's still not work. I used Visual Studio 2015, so I also tried with Code::Blocks with gcc, but I can also see the message of 'terminated called after throwing an instance of '`std::system_error`''. The following code is simplified version for test.

```
#include <thread>

void foo(){}

int main()
{
    for(; ;)
    {
        std::thread th1(foo);
        std::thread th2(foo);
        std::thread th3(foo);
        std::thread th4(foo);
        std::thread th5(foo);

        th1.join();
        th2.join();
        th3.join();
        th4.join();
        th5.join();
    }
}
```

I used 5 `thread`s because if I only use one `thread` it looked like just stopped without error. I checked the memory increment with Visual Studio 2015 debug tool and just Windows Task Manager. It looks destructor of `thread` doesn't work and it throws `std::system_error` because there's no more space, but I cannot understand why because I called `join()` so `thread`s should be deleted for each loop.

Is there any problem of repeating construct and destruct `thread` or some bug on `std::thread`?

Comment: Works at least looping 100 times: http://ideone.com/3VnVTF

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ maybe at least 2~30 seconds needed (about 10^9 loops?)

Comment: Catch the exception and output its `what()` result. Also, run the code in a debugger to find out where the exception is thrown. That said, you are creating and destroying thread objects in a loop and a thread instance that is destroyed without being detached or joined first is a fatal error that will be signalled. In short, there is nothing wrong with your code, it's the implementation underneath that's wrong!

Comment: Just for the record, this works for several minutes on Linux using GCC and CLANG, without any issues.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I used `catch(...)` but crashed without no exception... but program crashed and debugger said there was exception on creating `thread`. I cannot understand why it works on Linux because there were memory increment on Windows. I even think about the possibility of some kind of OS bug, and I will test it on another PC later.

Comment: No problem with code in Visual Studio 2013.  Do you show all the code?

Comment: @Matt It's too long to show you all the code, but I could check the memory increment (maybe memory leaks) from just that test code. Did you run it about few minutes or check the program's memory usage on Windows Task Manager? If you cannot find anything strange, I think I should report it to Microsoft.

Comment: @D.Lucit, the memory usage is under 3M bytes

Comment: If the above code doesn't even reproduce the faulty behaviour, your whole question is off-topic, as it's completely useless to anyone else who doesn't have a chance to reproduce the problem (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please don't do that! Also, a literal `catch(...)` is usually useless, `catch(exception const&e)` and then output the reason. Also, you should configure the debugger so that it stops when the exception is thrown, so that you don't loose any info due to stack unwinding.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt That code reproduce the faulty behavior at least on my computer (Windows8.1). I cannot understand why it doesn't reproduced on Matt's computer. I tried both of debugger configuration about exception and `catch(exception e)` but only the debugger catch the exception and the `catch` cannot catch the exception on run time (just crashed with some message). I cannot understand why, and I know that the code on my question should work, but at least on my computer, it makes problem.

Comment: Good, then I just misunderstood you. Now, concerning catching exceptions, `catch(exception e)` doesn't work, because it would copy the exception and truncate it to the baseclass. Then, the actual exceptions's `what()` is irrelevant, which is why it must be `catch(std::exception const& e)`! If that doesn't catch it, at least we know it's not a C++ exception.